# Can't install imagemagick and rmagick on OSX Mavericks

Tags: macos, imagemagick, rmagick

I'm having problems to install imagemacgick and rmagick

```
➜  scripts  brew install imagemagick
Error: You must `brew link freetype' before imagemagick can be installed
➜  scripts  brew install freetype
Warning: freetype-2.5.3_1 already installed
➜  scripts  brew unlink freetype && brew link freetype
Unlinking /usr/local/Cellar/freetype/2.5.3_1... 1 symlinks removed
Linking /usr/local/Cellar/freetype/2.5.3_1... Error: No such file or directory - /usr/local/Cellar/freetype/2.5.3/include/freetype2


brew remove freetype && brew install freetype
```

Uninstalling /usr/local/Cellar/freetype/2.5.3_1...
==> Downloading https://downloads.sf.net/project/machomebrew/Bottles/freetype-2.5.3
Already downloaded: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/freetype-2.5.3_1.mavericks.bottle.1.tar.gz
==> Pouring freetype-2.5.3_1.mavericks.bottle.1.tar.gz
Error: An unexpected error occurred during the `brew link` step
The formula built, but is not symlinked into /usr/local
No such file or directory - /usr/local/Cellar/freetype/2.5.3/include/freetype2
Error: No such file or directory - /usr/local/Cellar/freetype/2.5.3/include/freetype2

Comment: `brew remove freetype && brew install freetype` ?

Answer (score 0):

There is some problem with freetype

I've found a solution [here](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-php/issues/885):

- brew uninstall freetype
- brew install https://raw.github.com/mxcl/homebrew/04406ae9a0aa093aaaf61ab06dc1d81672c41fee/Library/Formula/freetype.rb
- brew install freetype
- brew install imagemagick

It worked for me

**Update:**
It seems it's not recommended to checkout the repository directly and you can install by using a link with the revision hash
I've updated my answer accordingly

Also, please note that i've used a more recent hash than the one in the link, otherwise imagemagick will complain about the version of libfreetype.6.dylib